# What is Paas, Hosting and SaaS

Tags: hosting, paas

What exactly are Paas, Hosting and SaaS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia to the rescue.

PaaS - Platform as a service

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service

SaaS - Software as a service

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service

Hosting

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_hosting_service

Heroku is not a DNS registrar. You can however buy domains elsewhere, such as Godaddy and add them to your Heroku app. By default you are given a free my-app-name.herokuapp.com domain. After you have purchased a domain, to "point it at heroku", you'll need to add a CNAME record which points to your my-app-name.herokuapp.com domain.

When you purchase a domain, you'll need to host the records on a DNS server. Some registrars provide free DNS hosting, others charge extra for it. You can purchase DNS hosting from [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) for $0.50 per domain / month. To use Amazon, you would need to change the domain's name servers to Amazon's.

Domain > Name Server > Hosting provider / PaaS.

One limitation of using Heroku is that you cant use apex domains. You must use a subdomain eg. `www.example.com` instead of just `example.com`. This is a DNS limitation - you can't have CNAME records on the apex. It must be an A record. Amazon Route 53 is one of the few providers that allow virtual CNAME records on the apex. It's basically an A record that is frequently updated. Each time your Heroku app sleeps due to inactivity, you may be given a new ip address when it restarts.

Further reading on [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) on Wikipedia.

ps: Happy New Year!

Comment: One of the benefits of using platforms such as Heroku instead of traditional VPS's is their ability to scale with minimal effort. You can provision new servers by simply dragging a slider in the admin gui. You can spend more time building your app than managing, configuring and supporting servers. It's great for 1-10 servers. Once you get past that, you're most likely cashed up enough for a more dedicated system and some sysadmins.